# Agrupar Array JS e PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Estou fazendo uma consulta de informações na base de dados estilo o Google Instant, onde você digita e já aparece os resultados abaixo.

Consegui fazer isso, mas eu quero que esses resultados venham agrupados. Estou fazendo a consulta na tabela de **Produtos** e **Serviços** e quero trazer primeiro os resultados de produtos e depois o de serviços separados por um subtítulo.

O que eu consegui até agora:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebam acima que ele está trazendo os produtos e serviços todos juntos.

Agora vem o código:

### JS

```
// Resultados da Pesquisa
$('#q').on('keyup', function(){
    var str = $(this).val();
    var res = $("#resultados");
    var row = $("#resultados > ul");
    $.ajax({
        url: urlBase + '/consulta',
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        data: { str: str },
        success: function(result){
            res.css('display', 'block');
            row.html('');
            if(str != ''){
                $.each(result, function(index, value){
                    if(value == 'Produtos'){
                        row.append('<li class="subtitle">Produtos</li>');
                    }
                    else if(value == 'Serviços'){
                        row.append('<li class="subtitle">Serviços</li>');   
                    }
                    else
                        row.append('<li>'+value+'</li>');
                });
            }
            else{
                str = '';
                res.css('display', 'none');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

### PHP

```
# Consulta no Site
public function postConsulta(){
    $str = Input::get('str');

    $arrProd = array(0 => 'Produtos');
    $arrServ = array(0 => 'Serviços');

    $produtos = DB::table('produtos')
                ->join('categorias', 'categorias.id', '=', 'produtos.id_categoria')
                ->select('categorias.slug as slug_categoria', 'produtos.slug as slug', 'produtos.id', 'produto')
                ->where('produto', 'like', "%$str%")
                ->take(5)
                ->get();

    $servicos = Servico::where('servico', 'like', "%$str%")->get();

    foreach ($produtos as $value) {
        $arrProd['p'.$value->id] = "<a href='".URL::to('produtos/'.$value->slug_categoria.'/'.$value->slug)."'>".$value->produto."</a>";
    }

    foreach ($servicos as $value) {
        $arrServ['s'.$value['id']] = "<a href='".URL::to('servicos/'.$value->slug)."'>".$value['servico']."</a>";
    }

    return array_merge($arrProd, $arrServ);
}
```

Eu quero que traga assim:

```
• Produtos
    JFL SHC 3.0 PA
    JFL RRC 500 (5 CANAIS)
    JFL RRC 400 (4 CANAIS)
    JFL RRC 300 (3 CANAIS)
    JFL RRC 200 (2 CANAIS)
• Serviços
    Segurança Patrimonial
    Monitoramento 24 Horas
    Portaria e Recepção
    Segurança Armada e Desarmada
```

Não consigo pensar em jeito de fazer, estou me sentindo **um lixo**!

Comment: Não deu certo. Ele nem mostra os resultados. Eu acho que o problema está na hora do `merge` no PHP, achei que usando essa função ele juntaria, mas ficaria na sequência do código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer. Mas não sei se isso pode se considerar um **RTA** ou **POG**.

Como vocês podem ver na montagem do `array` no PHP, eu coloco na chave um `p` quando é produto, concatenando com o `id` do mesmo. E quando é serviço eu coloco o `s` concatenando com o `id` do mesmo.

Mas no subtítulo eu não coloquei o `p` e nem `s`. Então eu pensei: se eu colocar o `p` e o `s` também no subtítulo posso fazer a ordenação por chave.

Foi o que eu fiz:

```
$arrProd = array('p0' => '<li class="subtitle">Produtos</li>');
$arrServ = array('s0' => '<li class="subtitle">Serviços</li>');
```

E depois a ordenação usando a função `ksort` que ordena o `array` por chaves:

```
ksort($arrProd);
ksort($arrServ);

return array_merge($arrProd, $arrServ);
```

Comment: O que significa RTA ?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Recurso Técnico Alternativo, vulgo gambiarra.

Comment: kkkkk é uma palavra com eufemismo para gambiarra, por que POG  já é  enfático nisso :)